# Warning: ldap_start_tls() [function.ldap-start-tls]: Unable to start TLS: Server is unavailable

Tags: php, starttls

> Warning: ldap_start_tls() [function.ldap-start-tls]: Unable to start TLS: Server is unavailable in /var/www/html/testldap/index.php on line 13
>   Ldap_start_tls failed

My configuration is as follows

Centos 5.7 PHP Version 5.3.3

php53-ldap configured. No matter what I try to do , the starttls issue is giving me a headache. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your code, and advise what LDAP provider you are trying to connect to.

Answer (score 2):

Well, what a fun journey I have been on with this one.

The problem you are having is that your machine does not accept the server's certificate as valid. The simple work around to this is to disable the check, which is done in the ldap.conf file, or with an environment variable.

You can edit the file at `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` (`c:\openldap\sysconf\ldap.conf` on Windows) or create one if it doesn't already exist and put this line in it:

```
TLS_REQCERT never
```

...or you can create an environment variable named `LDAPTLS_REQCERT` with the value `never`.

Once I had done either of those things, the following script worked for me:

```
<?php

  // Settings
  $host = 'server.domain.local';
  $port = 389;
  $user = 'administrator';
  $pass = 'password';

  // Connect, set options and bind
  $ds = ldap_connect($host, $port);
  if (!ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)) exit('Could not disable referrals');
  if (!ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0)) exit('Could not disable referrals');
  if (!ldap_start_tls($ds)) exit('Could not start TLS');
  if (!ldap_bind($ds, $user, $pass)) exit('Bind operation failed');

  // A quick list operation to make sure it worked
  if (!$result = ldap_list($ds, 'dc=domain,dc=local', 'objectClass=*')) exit('List operation failed');
  print_r(ldap_get_entries($ds, $result));
```

Annoyingly, neither `putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');` nor `$_ENV['LDAPTLS_REQCERT'] = 'never';` will work - you have to either create the config file or statically set the variable.

If you want to validate the certificates, you will need to do some further reading on how to configure OpenLDAP properly.

Sources for this:

- http://marc.info/?l=php-windows&m=116127873321748&w=2
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-start-tls.php
- http://linux.die.net/man/5/ldap.conf

Comment: Life saver. `mkdir C:\openldap\sysconf`.

Comment: @DaveRandom , I am able to connect doing this method on a LDAP server that allows lower security protocols such as TLS 1.1 and lower, but I tried to connect securely to a LDAP server that only allows TLS 1.2. I get a "Cannot connect to LDAP Server" (if I connect unsecurely, it is successful). I know for sure that TLS 1.2 protocol is enabled on my side. Made sure by checking the windows registry and also was able to connect via TLS 1.2 through a browser (such as IE, chrome). Any clue on what my issue might be. Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you [installed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php) PHP --with-ldap[=DIR]?

Also:

1. Do not use ldap_start_tls() if you've already connected to the LDAP Server via SSL e.g. "ldaps://hostame".
2. call ldap_connect() with ldap:// rather than ldaps:// for ldap_start_tls() to succeed

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-start-tls.php).

Comment: I have configured php with php-ldap

I have the settings from my system admin guys of active directory and hence will need to use them.