# Php ldap bind - Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials

Tags: php, binding, ldap, credentials

I have checked tons of solutions for this problem and yet none of them solved my problem, I am building a laravel app and need to authenticate users against AD for that purpose I found that I can accomplish this with the following script

```
  $ldap_dn = "uid=user,dc=example,dc=local";

  $ldap_password = "somePassword";
  $ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldap://domain") or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

  ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
  ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
  $bind = ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_password);


  if($bind)
  {
    return "Authenticated";
  }
```

However, I keep getting the same error, no matter how I change my parameters. Here's a list of things I've tried:
modifying this line `$ldap_dn = "uid=user,dc=example,dc=local";` to:

- $ldap_dn = "**cn**=user,dc=example,dc=local";
- $ldap_dn = "uid=**domain\user**,dc=example,dc=local";
- $ldap_dn = "**sAMAccountName**=user,dc=example,dc=local";

I am sure my credentials are correct, I have tested this in C# and it works perfectly with the following script:

```
public static bool IsAuthenticated(string ldap, string usr, string pwd)
    {
        bool authenticated = false;

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ldap, usr, pwd);
            object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
            authenticated = true;
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException cex)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return authenticated;
    }
```

I even tried compiling a c# dll to bypass ldap binding in php but got to a dead-end with that solution too...

Comment: Possibly because you're not connecting securely (as required by AD), so the password is being transmitted in plaintext. Try using [`ldap_start_tls()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-start-tls.php).

Comment: @timclutton what do I pass as argument?

Comment: The LDAP resource, i.e. `ldap_start_tls($ldap_con);`.

Comment: Hmm, I am getting this error now
"Unable to start TLS: Server is unavailable", testing this solution now
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473406/warning-ldap-start-tls-function-ldap-start-tls-unable-to-start-tls-server

Comment: Actually, just testing this locally I can bind successfully without using `ldap_start_tls()`. I must be misremembering and TLS is required only when changing a password.